# SVN+SSH : How to setup "Authentication Realm" Username and Password Prompt + Key authorization

Tags: linux, ubuntu, svn, ssh, terminal

I have a newly started server in which I'm importing my old SVN repo into.  The older server that used

`svn co svn://<ip>/file/directory`

to check out files and when done it would ask for a prompt of username and password, established within my repos `conf/passwd` file. As well, the option for username and password were enabled by editing the `svnserve.conf` file

Now I have a new server setup over svn+ssh, that is we now access and checkout our repo using

```
svn co svn+ssh://svn@host/path/direcotry
```

But using this method it only checks for key authorization, and once checked it automatically accepts the user without prompting for username and password.

Is there anyway to get BOTH username/password prompt AND key authorization through svn+ssh

Comment: Simply change `svn co svn+ssh://svn@host/path/direcotry` to `svn co svn+ssh://host/path/direcotry`. By removing the user `svn` it will attempt to login as the current user. If the current user's key is not registered in his/her own directory, ssh will prompt for password. The user however should have read/write permission to the repo if they are to checkin codes. The user's `/path/directory` should also point to the `/path/directory` of user `svn`. Note that the path here is relative to the user's home. I believe `svn` will allow absolute path by using `//home/svn/path/directory`.

Comment: Or the user may use their username for example user joe `svn co svn+ssh://joe@host/path/direcotry`.